# `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pacman_mirrors'` の解決法

Tags: linux

### 環境

- OS: Manjaro ARM Linux armv7l
- Host: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3
- Kernel: 4.14.66-1-MANJARO-ARM
- Packages: 645 (pacman)
- Shell: zsh 5.5.1
- Terminal: /dev/pts/1
- CPU: BCM2835 (4) @ 1.400GHz
- Memory: 779MiB / 935MiB

### 適切なミラーに更新したかった

ミラーを更新しようと`sudo pacman-mirrors --fasttrack && sudo pacman -Syy`しようとしたところ、

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pacman-mirrors", line 23, in <module>
    from pacman_mirrors import pacman_mirrors
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pacman_mirrors'
```

となってしまい、pacman-mirrorsが使えません。

同様のエラーを解決できた方がいればその解決方法をご教示いただきたいです。

よろしくお願い致します。

確認が必要な情報があれば適宜追加させていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

下記のサイトでは「pacman-mirrors の再インストールを試してみて」とやり取りがありました。

[[RESOLVED] Error with pacman-mirrors](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/resolved-error-with-pacman-mirrors/78611)

> Try reinstalling pacman-mirrors.
>
> ```
> $ sudo pacman -S pacman-mirrors
> ```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
実は検証済で、`error: target not found: pacman-mirrors`となってしまい、これを解決できませんでした。

Comment: ミラーサイトのリストが古いのではないでしょうか？ 例えば、`sudo pacman -U https://mirror.scachemaille.ch/manjaro-arm/stable/any/core/pacman-mirrorlist-20191121-1-any.pkg.tar.xz` などとしてアップデートしてみると良いかも知れません。

Comment: なるほど。そのやり方は知りませんでした。ありがとうございます。試してみます!